# monacaのバックエンドでコレクションアイテムの合計をとりたい

Tags: monaca

単純なカウンターアプリを作成しており、ユーザごとに誰が何回カウントアップしたかを集計したいです。

SQLでいうcount(id)みたいな処理は可能でしょうか。

Comment: 集計対象のレコードは具体的にどのようなものなのでしょうか？履歴のような単位で、DBに格納されていて、そこから特定フィールドの合計を計算するのでしょうか？

Comment: おっしゃる通りです。
フロント側のボタンを押すと、countというフィールドに1が入るようにしているので、特定フィールド（この場合count）の合計でも、count(id)のような処理でも同じ結果になると考えています。

Answer (score 1):

下記のコードはどうでしょうか？

・コレクション名は、仮置きで「counters」としています。
・取得対象を「count」フィールドとしています。
・「count」フィールドが1のアイテムのみ取得し、「totalItems」で合計を求めています。

```
var counters = monaca.cloud.Collection("counters");
counters.findMine('count == 1', "", {propertyNames: ["count"]})
.done(function(result)
{
   console.log('Total items found: ' + result.totalItems);
})
.fail(function(err)
{
  console.log("Err#" + err.code +": " + err.message);
});
```